# How to get JSON output as NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Working in Objective-C where I need to parse JSON. So after parsing successfully.

Below is my code :

```
-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            self.allKeysArray = [dict allKeys];

 if ([self.allKeysArray containsObject:@"nDetail"]) {

                if ([dict valueForKey:@"nDetail"]) {

 _tempNutrientArray = [[[dict valueForKey:@"nDetail"] valueForKey:@"nTypeCode"] valueForKey:@"value"];
         }
     }
 }

NSLog(@"N Array : @%@", _tempNutrientArray);

}
```

I need to convert this in string format each an every value.

My output :

```
N Array : @(
    "ENER-",
    FAT,
    FASAT,
    CHOAVL,
    "SUGAR-",
    "PRO-",
    NACL
)
```

**Required Output :**

```
 N Array : @("ENER-","FAT","FASAT","CHOAVL","SUGAR-","PRO-","NACL")
```

So how should I convert it to string format. Please help me.

Comment: convert array back to json string?

Comment: You want to convert your array in to string or want to convert array objects in string?

Comment: I want each an every element within the array should be string.

Comment: Like this :  Array : @(
    "ENER-",
   " FAT",
   " FASAT",
    "CHOAVL",
    "SUGAR-",
    "PRO-",
    "NACL"
)

Comment: @aadityaa use compnent spearated by ""

Comment: NSArray *arr = [YOUR_WHOLE_STRING componentsSeparatedByString:@""];  and you got arr that store single single value

Comment: Yes I have used it as per below answer, but getting string, how should it be in array format. please help I'm new to it.

Comment: @aditya if you want it in string you can cast it in string while using it's value like    `NSString *desireValue = [tempNutrientArray[IndexPath] stringValue];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate the whole array to make all object as a proper string. This may be fast operation.

you can use this code:

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"",@"", nil];
NSMutableArray *arrNew = [NSMutableArray new];

[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *plainstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
    [arrNew addObject:plainstr];
}];
```

The arrNew will be the array with string..

Better you convert it to string when you are fetching it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting Array to String

```
NSString * myString = [_tempNutrientArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

If you want any Character between the string give it in `componentsJoinedByString:@"GIVE_IT_HERE"`

Comment: I required output like this : Array : @( "ENER-", " FAT", " FASAT", "CHOAVL", "SUGAR-", "PRO-", "NACL" )

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have create one variable that store your whole string from your response after that use my code.

```
 NSString *tempstring = @"ENER- FAT FASAT CHOAVL SUGAR- PRO- NACL";
 NSArray *arr = [tempstring componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
 NSLog(@"%@",arr);
 NSLog(@"First value : %@",[arr objectAtIndex:0]);
 NSLog(@"Second value : %@",[arr objectAtIndex:1]);
 NSLog(@"Third value : %@",[arr objectAtIndex:2]);
```

now check arr value you got all string in array that you want .

**Output :**

```
(
    "ENER-",
    FAT,
    FASAT,
    CHOAVL,
    "SUGAR-",
    "PRO-",
    NACL
)

First value : ENER-
Second value : FAT
Third value : FASAT
```

Comment: Yes I have used this,  NSMutableArray *arr = [_tempNutrientArray componentsJoinedByString:@""]; but received warning i.e incompatible pointer types initializing to NSString.

Comment: @aadityaa use Nsarray instead of NSMubtaleArray . so you got it.

Comment: @aadityaa check now i made it and run my machine there is no any warning i have got.

Comment: @aadityaa did you got your solution ?

Answer (score 0):

As the required output you need, you can try:

```
-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            self.allKeysArray = [dict allKeys];

 if ([self.allKeysArray containsObject:@"nDetail"]) {

                if ([dict valueForKey:@"nDetail"]) {

 _tempNutrientArray = [[[dict valueForKey:@"nDetail"] valueForKey:@"nTypeCode"] valueForKey:@"value"];
         }
     }
 }

NSString *finalString = @"";
[_tempNutrientArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *plainstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj];
    if (plainstr)
        finalString = [finalString stringByAppendingString:plainstr];
}];

NSLog(@"N Array : @%@", finalString);

}
```